# How to use Flex in a Row for its two Child Views in React Native?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-native

My code is like this---

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text,Alert,StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const data = ['All','Electronics','Baby and Child','Property']; 

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    itemStyles: {
        color: "#F456A3",
        fontSize:30,
        fontWeight:"bold",

    },
    CategoryStyle: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        flexDirection:'row'
    }
});

export default class FilterScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.test;
    }

    renderCategories = () =>{
        //Alert.alert(data[0]);
        this.test=data.map(item => {
            return(
                <View key={item} style={styles.CategoryStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.itemStyles}>{item}</Text>
                </View>
                )
        })

        return this.test;
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>hello world</Text>
                {this.renderCategories()}
            </View>
            )
    }
}
```

I have to apply styling to the Text present in render categories such that it should come with 2 text in a row. So, here there will be 2 rows with 2 texts.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `styles.itemStyles` set it to `width: '50%'` and add `flexWrap` to parent. Try this:

```
const styles=StyleSheet.create({
    itemStyles: {
        color: "#F456A3",
        fontSize:30,
        fontWeight:"bold",
        width: '50%' ///////////////// i added this

    },
    CategoryStyle: {
        flex:1,
        justifyContent:'center',
        flexDirection:'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap' ///////// added this
    }
});
```

Here is a snack expo that works - https://snack.expo.io/BJY_WnrrG

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textPink]}>a</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textBlue]}>b</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.text, styles.textPink]}>c</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end', 
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    alignContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'steelblue'
  },
  text: {
    width: '50%'
  },
  textBlue: {
    backgroundColor: 'skyblue'
  },
  textPink: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink'
  }
});
```

When items wrap, you get the new style property of `alignContent` check it out - http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#aligncontent

Also when items wrap, `justifyContent` only affects rows where there is space left over, as seen in the third text item above.

Comment: @Aayushi Try `width: '50%'` instead of `flex:0.5`

Comment: for me it is coming with all the four items in the same row

Comment: @Aayushi you have to put `flexWrap: 'wrap'` on the parent, so for `CategoryStyle`.